# Why does the Twitter app not share animated gifs?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I recently noticed that when sharing an animated .gif that I generate from my app, the **official Twitter app** will only share it as a static image.

Previously, I thought everything was working because when I shared the same type of animated .gif with an **unofficial Twitter app** (Tweetcaster), it properly shared it as an animated .gif.

The thing I'm questioning is whether this is an issue on my end or with the official Twitter app?  I ask this because when sharing an animated .gif from the Android Gallery with the official Twitter app, it is also posted as a static .gif.

Here's the code in question:

```
public void shareGif(String path)
    {       
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/gif");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a sharing option"));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested setting the `setType` to explicitly `intent.setType("image/gif")`?

Comment: Most likely, it is the Twitter app that is affecting matters. Choose some other sharing option and see if you get your animated GIF as output -- if you do, then clearly it would be the Twitter app.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk I'll try that, I'd love if the solution is that simple.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I get an animated .gif from email, hangouts, other Twitter apps, etc. I'm just thinking maybe this official Twitter app isn't necessarily the issue, but maybe it just needs different information/data of some type to work properly.

Comment: I doubt it, though the MIME type fix suggested in the comments here might help.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk Just tried it, set the mimeType to image/gif - same result. Official Twitter app posts a static image.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried using a different app to share on Twitter, and the same thing happens. The "Gif" files cannot be shared. Could be a Twitter app bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. I was loading URIs from the drawables and for whatever it was not animating.

I fixed my problem by implementing a custom [file provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) and loaded GIFs from the assets folder.

Also it was very important to add this flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supports looping GIFs. If your animated GIF doesn’t loop and plays a single time, it will display as a static image.